# Information for localization

Tags: localization, internationalization, units-of-measurement

Is there a list with complete information about caracteristics like:

- currency
- date and time (including if it is 12 or 24 hours) format
- measurement units (distance, speed, temperature...)
- preferred language
- masks for phone and local documents
- timezones (at least the main ones / variations if daylight saving time is applicable)
- decimal and thousand separators

for countries around the world?

I am doing it myself, however, as it takes too long to gather the data, I tought maybe someone have already have it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.
Start with CLDR, the Common Locale Data Repository (http://cldr.unicode.org/)

Or if you want to honor the locale preferences in your application, use standard I18N APIs (from you platform, whatever that is, or a popular library, like ICU, http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about this. So, I have a standard to follow.

Comment: Very interesting ! Thanks !  Neverthesless currencies don't seem to refer to country code (core/common/bcp47/currencies.xml) and units, while there seem to be all of them and translated in local language (ex: json/main/de/units.json) it's not told which one are really in use (ex: you don't  use square inches in Germany, even if this unit is in the translated list).

Comment: core/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml has info on the number of decimal digits, rounding, region, and period of time when the currency was used. core/common/bcp47/currencies.xml has a friendly name, but you don't want to use that. core/common/main/<locale>.xml has translations of the currency in all supported locales. So you can look for "JPY" in fr.xml and you will find "yen japonais", and plural forms ("yen/yens japonais") and a narrow form ("¥"). CLDR can be quite complex to understand (with inheritance and all), this is why I would recoment using an existing library (ICU).

Comment: For the type of measurement units used, core/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml measurementData has the info (the whole world uses metric system, except for "LR MM US"). Might be handy to know what unit is metric and what is US, true. Maybe a feature request. Things are complex though. Some countries use metric for some things, and inch for others. For instance km and m for distance, but inch for pipe diameters. Air traffic control uses feets for heights, no matter the country. So "what country uses the metric system" is not granular enough.

Answer (score 1):

For **currencies** you can rely on international standard ISO 4217. It also refers to the country code of each currency code. This [website](http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html) provides this dataset for download.

For **date formats**, the best reference seems to be [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

The **measurement units** is a very complex domain, because you need to know which dimension you measure (speed, distance, volume, ...) and the units (paper size in cm is not the same as road distance in km).   [Here](http://www.cleavebooks.co.uk/dictunit/dictunit1.htm) you have some lists per type of units, but not per country. [This](http://chartsbin.com/view/d12) website shows a list of system of measurements in use per country.  You'll see that fortunately ùany of them share the metric system, so taht you could use an approach "by exception" documenting yourself only on the remaining ones".

For **languages**, you have international standard [ISO 639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) or [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) , but it's country independent.  You can look at reference lists for locale such as [here](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp): it associates a language code to a country code, so that you could complete the standard information. Note that some countries have several language, and you cannot and should not decide which one is preferred.

For **telephone masks**, there is only an international [list of prefix](http://countrycode.org/). The usage vary greately accross countries.  Some have fixed format, some use variable formats, some have zone prefixes and some not. Sometimes there is even no clear standard in the country and there are several coexisting usages. I'm not aware of any global list of these.

For **timezones** around the world, you could have a look at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) which is extremely comprehensive.

For **decimal and thousand** separators, it's not an international standard. Again I'd suggest to refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Comment: Good sources, I can relyon then when no standard is defined